# HOW TO run pose estimation on single image with TensorFlow-Lite?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, pose-estimation

I recently used [this sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/pose_estimation/android) of great TensorFlow lite in android.

I can use this project correctly, but I want to estimate poses on single images too (not just in real time mode). so I tried to reach my goal! but unfortunately I couldn't! and those disappointing codes are here:

```
private fun runOnSimpleImage() {
    val detector = MoveNet.create(this, device, ModelType.Lightning)
    detector.let { detector ->
        simpleDetector = detector
    }
    simpleDetector?.estimatePoses(templateBitmap)?.let {persons->
        VisualizationUtils.drawBodyKeypoints(
            templateBitmap,
            persons, false
        )
    }

    showOutputBitmap(templateBitmap)
}
```

Also I search it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321798/how-to-pass-single-image-to-tensorflow-lite). but I couldn't solve my problem yet.
and my result is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately my code is not wrong! and it works correctly. and you can use it!

The problem was in method that I used to convert my **drawable** image to **Bitmap**.

I used to use these codes:

```
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.resized,theme)

templateBitmap = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
```

But when I changed those to something like this:

```
 templateBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.resized)
```

my problem solved.